# NullPointerException when creating array from String.split

Tags: java, arrays, file

I'm reading a file and each line of the file does not always have the same number of elements. Some lines have 2 elements, while others may have 4 or 6 elements. So what I'm doing is creating a temporary array based on how the line is split. The problem here is that I get a java.lang.NullPointerException for `String[] currentLine`. But the program still reads the content of `currentLine[1]`:

```
        boolean needData = true;    
        String path = "foo/" + filename + ".bar";
        File dataFile = null;
        BufferedReader bufReader = null;
        String line = null;

        if (needData) // always true
        {
            try
            {
                dataFile = new File(path);
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(dataFile);
                bufReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

                if (file.exists())
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        line = bufReader.readLine();
                        String[] currentLine = line.split(" "); // Error
                        String lineStartsWith = currentLine[0];

                        switch(lineStartsWith)
                        {
                          case "Name:" :
                              System.out.println(currentLine[1]);
                          break;
                        }
                    } // end while loop
                }
                bufReader.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Couldn't load " + filename + ".bar");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: if `line` is `null` then its obvious that you will get NPE.

Comment: You should check return value of bufReader.readLine() before you split line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`BufferedReader`'s `readLine` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) will eventually return `null`, indicating that there is no more input to read.

> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

However, you have set up an infinite loop.  You're attempting to process a line that doesn't exist.

Check if `line` is `null` in the condition of the `while` loop.  This will stop the loop once the last line has already been processed.

```
while( (line = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Remove readLine call here
    // The rest of the while loop body is the same
```

Answer (score 1):

The docu for `public String readLine()` of Buffered Reader says:

*A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, **or null** if the end of the stream has been reached*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

So, you are just hitting the end of the file, because you are never leaving the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your loop:

```
while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null )
{
  String[] currentLine = line.split(" "); // Error
  String lineStartsWith = currentLine[0];

  switch(lineStartsWith)
  {
  case "Name:" :
  System.out.println(currentLine[1]);
  break;
  }
}
```